# Regex Remove articles from title - the, an, a

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will match the first letter of a song title without articles like "the", "an", "a". I'm writing a custom import script for Mediatomb which uses javascript. I need to be able to put songs in alphabetical folders.

Example: "Panama.mp3" would be in folder "P", "The Gambler.mp3" would be in folder "G"

Comment: Sounds like a regular expression might not be the best solution; why not just check for your word list directly?

Comment: This could go wrong with non-english titles.

Comment: It seems like what you want isn't to match against a regex, but to strip some specific initial words from a string. Therefore, as Carl suggested, the best approach would be to simply check for the worlds directly.

Comment: Depending on the language you're using, there may be simpler ways to do this than regex.

Comment: Regex seems like a good fit for me. All english titles and if they're not, I can deal with that. I just need the first letter after an article if one exists. Regex seems like a perfect match for that especially using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer above, this is what I came up with. Let me know if there's any way to improve upon it.

```
(?:(the |a |an ))*(\S{1})(\S*)
```

Comment: You may want to add a ^ at the begining to match begining of line/string. Also, there COULD be more than one space after the article, so I'd re-write that article-capture part as ^(?:(the|a|an) +)

Comment: You have two sets of parentheses around the list of articles.  Only one is marked as non-capturing.  Thus, the first letter will appear in the 2nd group.  Also, you don't need `{1}`.  Furthermore, what's the point of the `(\S*)`?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what flavour of regex you're using but there are: [non-capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)
you miught be able to use it like this:

```
(?:(the |a |an ))([a-zA-Z])
```

Capture the 3rd group and that should always be the first letter (excluding the "the, a, an,...".

Edit: Meant to say capture the SECOND group for that first letter. Also make sure you run this case-insensitive. And get a good regular expression test tool (I like Expresso, but there's others).

Edit2: made some refinements ;)
`(?:(the|a|an) +)?([a-zA-Z0-9])`

Comment: Your regex there _requires_ the leading article. You might want to stick a ? after the non-capture group.

Comment: also the regex requires exactly one space - may be better to include any whitespace

Comment: Thanks for the hints I think I got one that works.
(?:(the |a |an ))*(\S{1})(\S*)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript example -

```
const regex = /(?:(the|a|an) +)/g; 
const str = `the cat in the hat a hare `; 
const subst = ` `;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Non-capturing group (?:(the|a|an) +)

1st Capturing Group (the|a|an)

1. 1st Alternative "the" matches the characters the literally (case
   sensitive)
2. 2nd Alternative "a"matches the character a literally (case sensitive)
3. 3rd Alternative "an" matches the characters an literally (case sensitive)

   - matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
   - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   - g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

Answer (score 1):

The one that worked for me to find articles in a list of movie names in javascript was this one:

```
/^(a |the |an )/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myregexp = /^(?:(?:the|a|an)\s+)?(\S)/i;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```